# imap bodytext format issue

Tags: php, imap

i have the following function:

```
public function getMails()
{
    $mails = array();
    $numMessages = imap_num_msg($this->imap);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numMessages; $i++)
    {
        $header = imap_header($this->imap, $i);

        $fromInfo = $header->from[0];
        $replyInfo = $header->reply_to[0];

        $details = array(
            "fromAddr" => (isset($fromInfo->mailbox) && isset($fromInfo->host))
                ? $fromInfo->mailbox . "@" . $fromInfo->host : "",
            "fromName" => (isset($fromInfo->personal))
                ? $fromInfo->personal : "",
            "replyAddr" => (isset($replyInfo->mailbox) && isset($replyInfo->host))
                ? $replyInfo->mailbox . "@" . $replyInfo->host : "",
            "replyName" => (isset($replyInfo->personal))
                ? $replyInfo->personal : "",
            "subject" => (isset($header->subject))
                ? $header->subject : "",
            "udate" => (isset($header->udate))
                ? $header->udate : ""
        );

        $bodyText = imap_fetchbody($this->imap,$i,1.2);
        if(!strlen($bodyText)>0){
            $bodyText = imap_fetchbody($this->imap,$i,1);
        }
        $details['body'] = $bodyText;

        $uid = imap_uid($this->imap, $i);
        $current_mail = array('header'=>$header, 'from'=>$fromInfo, 'reply'=>$replyInfo, 'details'=>$details);

        $mails[$i] = $current_mail;
    } 
}
```

However there is a problem with the body text.

This is a test mail that i sendt from my email that looks like this:

```
Hello world

Med venlig hilsen

Marc Rasmussen

Besøg mig på MarcRasmussen.dk
```

However the body text is looks like this when taken from imap:

```
    Hello world=0A=
=0A=
Med venlig hilsen=0A=
=0A=
Marc Rasmussen=0A=
=0A=
Bes=F8g mig p=E5 MarcRasmussen.dk                     =
```

is there any buildin method in PHP to fix this issue?

Comment: That's "quoted-printable" format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: That is quoted printable encoding. There are many answers for this already that you can now search for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header of the MIME part you are working on (hint: it's available in IMAP's `BODYSTRUCTURE`) and decode it yourself. The two most common encoding are `quoted-printable` and `base64`. See [RFC 2045, chapter 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6) for details.

---

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the $options parameter of the imap_fetchbody function. Maybe with flag FT_INTERNAL combined with utf8_encode:

```
$bodyText = utf8_encode(imap_fetchbody($this->imap,$i,1, FT_INTERNAL));
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: I think that _is_ the internal format -- `=0A` is the quoted-printable representation of LF.

Comment: sadly this didnt help :S